# Create Twiiter app for iphone app

Tags: iphone, twitter, twitter-oauth

I integrate twitter API to app. And i created the app in twitter for that too. In this new twitter app creating interface there are no section for select application type. Previously there were section call Application Type and there were two radio buttons call client and browser. But in new Twitter interface its not there. I used my previous app key, i created for testing purposes to test my app in twitter and it works. So there is no error in integrating twitter to my app. The error in having when creating the app key. For new key my app is not posting data to twitter.

**This is the previous vesion.**

[image: Previous interface of Twitter app develop. And it has section call application type]

**This is the new version**

[image: There is no section call Application type]

Does any one have idea how to create twitter app correctly in this new version ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the new App creation in Twitter is a bit wierd!

Fill out the required fields of the 'Create an application' form and save it.  Now go back and edit the new app - and there are more options than before.

Now you can set the twitter app to read+write (it defaults to just read).

Save that, and you should be set :)